# getting nested objects in mongoose

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to retrieve an array of objects in mongoose using code that looks like this.

```
 mongoPlaces
            .find({
                'person.types': {$in: ["student"]}
            })
            .select('family')
            .lean()
            .limit(3)
            .exec(function (err, families) {
               console.log()

            })
```

the results is something like this

```
[
 0: family:{objects}
 1: family:{objects}
 2: family:{objects}
]
```

and I need something like this

```
[
 0: {objects}
 1: {objects}
 2: {objects}
]
```

is there some way to retrieve the contents of an object instead of the object itself using mongoose without having to make a loop and correct the array or is there any other way to make this cleanly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to do this with mongoose, but there are ways of making it cleanly:

```
mongoPlaces
    .find({
        'person.types': {$in: ["student"]}
    })
    .select('family')
    .lean()
    .limit(3)
    .exec(function (err, docs) {
        var families = docs.map(function pluckFamily(doc) {
            return doc.family;
        });
        return families;
    });
```

In this example, `map` feeds each retrieved document to the function `pluckFamily`, and forms another array with all the values that that function returned.

If you're going to do a lot of this, you may want to check out the underscore library. It includes a [pluck function](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck).

Comment: Thanks! this was very usefull!